# JQuery/Javascript issue in ie7 and ie8

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Part of this doesn't work in ie8 and ie7 and I'm not sure why. It works in all other browsers tested: IE9, Chrome and FF.

```
function onCheckChange() {

    var rowCount = 0 //amount of rows selected
    $("input.check-box-name:checked").each(function () {
        rowCount++;
    });

    if (rowCount > 0) {
        $("#lnkMulti_Remove").removeAttr("style");
        $("#lnkMulti_Remove").css('color', 'blue');
        if(rowCount == 1)
            $("#lnkMulti_Remove").html("Remove");
        else
            $("#lnkMulti_Remove").html("Remove Multiple");
       // $("#lnkMulti_Remove").removeAttr("style");
    } 
    else {
        $("#lnkMulti_Remove").html("Remove");
        $("#lnkMulti_Remove").css('color', 'gray');
     }
 }
```

Comment: any example we can check? or be more specific about error..

Comment: You're going to have to describe exactly what "doesn't work" means. Errors in the console? Errors in layout?

Comment: make a jsfiddle showing your code failing so we can test against it.

Comment: You could just write `var rowCount = $("input.check-box-name:checked").length`...

Comment: Add and remove classes, not style attributes!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue ended up being that the onchange function didn't include checking the box, in IE7 and IE8, so it waited to run the script until I changed focus, which wasn't initially obvious. When I changed the event to onclick everything worked more smoothly.

Thanks for all

Answer (score 0):

I've had problems in the past with using .html() in older IE versions.  You might consider using straight javascript for that.  eg:

```
document.getElementById('lnkMulti_Remove').innerHTML = 'Remove';
```